# Understanding the Opening Notation from *Statistical Decision Theory & Bayesian Analysis*

Tags: probability-theory, bayesian, decision-theory

I am having significant trouble understanding the notation used in the opening pages of *Statistical Decision Theory & Bayesian Analysis*. The book assumes that the reader has some basic familiarity with probability theory (which I do). Section 1 below outlines the book notation. Section 2 outlines my actual questions.

I'm sorry this post is so long, but I suspect that all of my questions are related to some core misunderstanding that can (hopefully) be explained/pointed out rather simply.

### 1 Book Definitions

#### 1.1 Parameter Space

> [image]

#### 1.2 Action Space

> [image]

#### 1.3 Random Variables and Sample Spaces

> [image]

### 2 Questions

> [image]
>   [image]

Let us assume, using the notation above, that $X : \mathscr{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous random variable.

1. Does the phrase from the book "$A ( A \subset \mathscr{X})$" mean anything more than the simple claim $A \subset \mathscr{X}$?
2. Do we have that

   $$
   P_\theta (A) = P_\theta (X \in A) = P_\theta (X^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) \cap A)?
   $$
3. Expanding on (2), does the notation

   $$
   P_\theta(A)
   $$

   imply that

   $$
   \mathscr{X} = (\ldots \times \Theta \times \ldots)
   $$

   so that with the notation

   $$
   \mathscr{X}_\theta = \{ (\ldots, \theta, \ldots) \mid \theta \in \Theta \} \subset \mathscr{X}
   $$

   we have that $P_\theta(A)$ can be further expanded as

   $$
   P_\theta(A) = P(\mathscr{X}_\theta \cap A)?
   $$
4. The subscript on the $\sum$ in the snippet shows that $x \in A$, and we know that $A \subset \mathscr{X}$ (where $\mathscr{X}$ is the sample space). But isn't this definition meaningless unless $x \in X$? That is, don't we have that $f : \text{Codomain}(X) \rightarrow [0,1]$? Clearly, $A$ needn't be a subset of $\text{Codomain}(X) = \mathbb{R}$.

---

**EDIT:** I have added the questions below, since they use the same notation as above:

> [image]

1. What on earth does

   $$
   P_\theta(\delta_1(X) = \delta_2(X) )
   $$

   mean? Is it short-hand for

   $$
   P_\theta(\delta_1(X)) = P_\theta(\delta_2(X) ) = 1?
   $$

   If so, would that mean we have a paramaterized probability distribution defined on the sample space $\mathscr{A}$?
2. Wrapping up, it seems we so far have at least two sample spaces: the first being $\mathscr{X} = X = \{x\}$, and the second being $\Theta$ (and, per the question above, perhaps even a third on $\mathscr{A})$. Is  this the case?

Answer (score 1):

> Let us assume, using the notation above, that $X : \mathscr{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous random variable.

That is *not* how they are using $X$ here.   Their notation is not fully compatible with the usual measure theoretical definitions.

They are using the measurable space *as* the sample space; that is using the values of the random variable *as* the outcomes.

Thus their definition of "random variable" is simply to use $X$ to denote the realised outcome.   So $X\in\mathscr X$ and $\mathscr X\subseteq \Bbb R^n$

> 1. Does the phrase from the book "$A ( A \subset \mathscr{X})$" mean anything more than the simple claim $A \subset \mathscr{X}$?

They do mean "... the event $A$, where $A\subset\mathscr X$, ...".

> 2. Do we have that $$
>    P_\theta (A) = P_\theta (X \in A) = P_\theta (X^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) \cap A)?
>    $$

No.  Usually when we write $P(X\in B)$ where $B$ was a subset of the measurable space we'd mean $P(X^{-1}(B))$, and $X^{-1}(B)$ would be the preimage of $B$, a subset of the sample space.  They're not doing it that way.

They just mean $P_\theta(X\in A)$, the probability that the realised outcome is in $A$, can be written as simple $P_\theta(A)$, the probability measure for event $A$.

> 3. Expanding on (2), does the notation $P_\theta(A)$ ....

No.   It is just the probability measure for the set of outcomes $A$ evaluated with parameter $\Theta$ equal to $\theta$.

> 4. The subscript on the $\sum$ in the snippet shows that $x \in A$, and we know that $A \subset \mathscr{X}$ (where $\mathscr{X}$ is the sample space). But isn't this definition meaningless unless $x \in X$? That is, don't we have that $f : \text{Codomain}(X) \rightarrow [0,1]$? Clearly, $A$ needn't be a subset of $\text{Codomain}(X) = \mathbb{R}$.

Like I said, they are not distinguishing between the sample space and the measureable space. An outcome is the measure, and event $A$ is a set of values for the random variable.

---

What they are doing is basically:

Let $\mathscr X=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ be the *sample space* for the roll of a biased die, and "random variable" $X$ be the result of a roll of that die. The distribution of $X$ follows a parametised probability mass function, $f_{X\mid\Theta}(x\mid\theta)$, for some parameter.   Let $A$ be the event for rolling an even result, so $A=\{2,4,6\}$. $$P_\theta(X\in A) {= P_\theta(\{2,4,6\}) \\= \sum_{x\in\{2,4,6\}} f_{X\mid\Theta}(x\mid\theta)}$$

---

> 1. What on earth does $P_\theta(\delta_1(X) = \delta_2(X) )$ mean?

It is the probability that the two rules will produce the same decision based on the same random outcome.   Basically, the probability that two random variables realise the same value.

Notice that $\delta_1, \delta_2$ map the sample space, $\mathscr X$, to a measurable space $\mathscr A$, as is the more usual definition of a random variable.

> 2. Wrapping up, it seems we so far have at least two sample spaces: the first being $\mathscr{X} = X = \{x\}$, and the second being $\Theta$ (and, per the question above, perhaps even a third on $\mathscr{A})$. Is  this the case?

No, you have the *one* sample space, though of course this may be *mapped* to various measurable spaces.

The sample space is associated with different *possible* probability measures, a familiy of parametised functions.   The parameter, $\Theta$, is *not* itself a random variable, but an unknown value.   However a measure for the *likelihood* that the paramter has some value when given particular evidence can be evaluated, *as if* this were a probability function, by Bayesian rules.

Comment: Just to clarify though: the notation used in this book is entirely different than the notation used in modern probability theory (as shown throughout, i.e., wikipedia), right?

Comment: In particular, the statements $P_\theta$ and $f(x|\theta)$ are being used completely different than they are [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution), right? That is: I was interpreting $f(x \mid \theta)$ as a conditional probability, but it's NOT a conditional probability, right?

Comment: I edited my question post to include some more content. I'm going to give you bounty afterwards for answering everything. Thanks for all your help on this long post.